# not all code paths return a value

Tags: c#, compiler-warnings

I got this compiler error, what is the problem?

```
public PictureBox getinfo(int i, int j)
{
    return grid[i, j];
}

public  PictureBox kingmove(int i, int j)///<-----the problem is here
{
    getinfo(i, j);

    if (i < 9)
    {
        grid[i, j] = grid[i - 1, j - 1];
    }
    else
    {
        grid[i, j] = grid[i, j];
    }
```

Comment: How about reading a good C# book? That way you don't need to ask so often on SO and delete the question afterwards...

Comment: This common error occurs when you miss a return for a function or you returning a wrong datatype compare to what function should return.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your second method has no `return` statement but a return-type different from `void`.
Add a `return` statement at the *end* of the method and not in the beginning.

And you could have edited that into your previous question.

The way you mix UI and game-logic is ugly too. The game-logic should know nothing about WinForms, picture-boxes,...
Instead write a function which takes a gamestate and renders it into some control/bitmap/picturebox/...

Comment: Additionally his call to `getinfo()` probably isn't doing anything useful, but that's an entirely different issue.