# How to remove the error 'not all code paths return a value' in c#

Tags: c#, if-statement

I often get this error in C#: 'not all code paths return a value'. I know the main reason behind this is an `if` not followed by an `else`. But what if I do not want the compiler to do anything if the condition inside `if` is not satisfied? For example, in the following program of trying to find the quotient without the use of `/` operator:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        public int Quotient( int dividend, int divisor)
        {
            int i, quotient = 0, remainder;
            i = divisor;
            while (i <= dividend)
            {
                i += divisor;
                quotient++;
                remainder = dividend - i;
                if (i == dividend || ((i < dividend) && (remainder < divisor)))
                {
                    return quotient;
                }
            }
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program obj = new Program();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the first number:");
            int a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the second number:");
            int b = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Program obj = new Program();
            int quotient = obj.Quotient(a, b);
            Console.WriteLine("The quotient is " + quotient);
        }
    }
}
```

Here I want the compiler to return `quotient` if the condition `(i == dividend || ((i < dividend) && (remainder < divisor)))` is true. In case this condition is false, I want the flow to go back to `while (i <= dividend)` and increase `i` and `quotient`. But the compiler says 'not all code paths return a value'. How am I supposed to get rid of this error? What am I supposed to give as the block of `else`? Also, is there a try-catch method to overcome this error?

Comment: add a *return 0* to the end of `Quotient`

Comment: Add `return quotient;` at the end of your method.

Comment: possible duplicate of [not all code paths return a value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4292067/not-all-code-paths-return-a-value)

Comment: The compiler is telling you "You're telling me about a function that's meant to return an `int` - however, there are ways for me to reach the end of this method and still not know what value I'm meant to return"

Comment: E.g. imagine you call this function as `Quotient(1,10);`. `i` becomes equal to `10`, it's *never* less than `1`, the `while` loop never runs - what should the function return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you get that error is because if your code does not go into the `if (i == dividend || ((i < dividend) && (remainder < divisor)))` condition or it fails the function has nothing to return - for simplicity you could just return `0` as a default:

```
public int Quotient( int dividend, int divisor)
{
    int i, quotient = 0, remainder;
    i = divisor;
    while (i <= dividend)
    {
        i += divisor;
        quotient++;
        remainder = dividend - i;
        if (i == dividend || ((i < dividend) && (remainder < divisor)))
        {
            return quotient;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The return type of Quotient is `int` but if the condition in while loop is not met `int` wont be return. Compiler ensures that function must return the `int` value. You only have return statement under condition and compiler assumes that condition might not met and method **wont return any value and gives you error**. Return some value un-conditionally from method.

```
public int Quotient( int dividend, int divisor)
{
    int i, quotient = 0, remainder;
    i = divisor;
    while (i <= dividend)
    {
        i += divisor;
        quotient++;
        remainder = dividend - i;
        if (i == dividend || ((i < dividend) && (remainder < divisor)))
        {
            return quotient;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```