# Try Catch Exceptions Error

Tags: c#, .net, error-handling

When I use `try catch exception` with this piece of code, I get the following error:

> "not all code paths return values"

My code:

```
   public System.Drawing.Image Scan()
    {
        try
        {

           const string formatJPEG = "{B96B3CAE-0728-11D3-9D7B-0000F81EF32E}";
            WIA.CommonDialog scanDialog = new WIA.CommonDialog();
            WIA.ImageFile imageFile = null;
            imageFile = scanDialog.ShowAcquireImage(WIA.WiaDeviceType.ScannerDeviceType, WIA.WiaImageIntent.GrayscaleIntent,

            WIA.WiaImageBias.MinimizeSize, formatJPEG, false, true, false);
            WIA.Vector vector = imageFile.FileData;
            System.Drawing.Image i = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(new System.IO.MemoryStream((byte[])vector.get_BinaryData()));

            return i;

        }
        catch (COMException ce)
        {
            if ((uint)ce.ErrorCode == 0x800A03EC)
            {
               return ce;

            }
        }
```

Comment: Because your function doesn't definitely return a value. `if ((uint)ce.ErrorCode == 0x800A03EC)` If this isn't true then your catch block doesn't return...

Comment: possible duplicate of [not all code paths return a value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4292067/not-all-code-paths-return-a-value)

Answer (score 4):

Change your `catch` block like below will work but still you face some issue. Because your method returns type `Image` and you are returning `COMException` in catch block. I suggest you to throw the exception or Log in catch block

```
if ((uint)ce.ErrorCode == 0x800A03EC)
{
    //DO LOGGING;
}
else
{
    throw ce;
}
```

Comment: Better to just call `throw` (without the ce).  If you include the ce, you will possibly lose some stack trace information.

Answer (score 1):

You have two different problems here.  First, your catch block won't return anything if the condition is not met.  Second, the return type within the catch block is not the same as the one inside of the try block.

You probably want something more like this in your catch block:

```
catch (COMException ce)
{
    if ((uint)ce.ErrorCode == 0x800A03EC)
        return null;  // Don't return anything if a specific code was found

    throw ce;         // Rethrow the exception for all other issues.
}
```

Comment: Get Exception from HRESULT: 0x80210015

Comment: It's better to just call `throw` rather than `throw ce` so you don't lose any stack trace information.